ng -v shows <error> for Angular version number
I have a new computer (it worked on my previous computer) and installed angular via cli and when looking at the information on the version the Angular:  appeared and I tried doing the same steps as this post (link) but they didn't work and I'm stuck on what to do next. I need this version for an existing project I am working on.
PS C:\Users\pnguy10\middleware-ui> ng v

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 11.2.19
Node: 16.20.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: <error>
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... flex-layout, forms, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.19 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1102.19 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.19 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.19 (cli-only)
@angular/cli                    11.2.19 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular             11.2.19 (cli-only)
@schematics/update              0.1102.19 (cli-only)
rxjs                            6.6.3 (cli-only)
typescript                      4.1.6 (cli-only)
webpack                         4.46.0 (cli-only)

I have npm version 7.24.0 to be supported for angular 11.2.19.
I've tried the below:
Delete node_modules folder and package-lock.json:
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json

Then install all packages again:
npm i

Reinstall the angular devkit:
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.19

Uninstalling and re-installing angular cli or angular-devkit/build-angular:
Uninstall commands:
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify

Re-install commands:
npm install -g @angular/cli@11.2.19
npm install -g @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.19

Sometimes I will also use
npm i 

and it'll upgrade the Angular CLI version to 16.xx.xx and that version is too high for the project.
I also tried setting this: npm config delete registry then re-installing but it didn't work.
Nothing is working and I'm still getting the error! Please help!
EDIT: After installing npm install -g @angular/core@11.2.14 the below showed.
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 11.2.19
Node: 16.20.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.2.14 (cli-only)
... core
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                             Version
-------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect           0.1102.19 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular       0.1102.19 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core                11.2.19 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics          11.2.19 (cli-only)
@angular/animations                 <error>
@angular/cdk                        <error>
@angular/cli                        11.2.19 (cli-only)
@angular/common                     <error>
@angular/compiler                   <error>
@angular/compiler-cli               <error>
@angular/flex-layout                <error>
@angular/forms                      <error>
@angular/material                   <error>
@angular/platform-browser           <error>
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic   <error>
@angular/router                     <error>
@schematics/angular                 11.2.19 (cli-only)
@schematics/update                  0.1102.19 (cli-only)
rxjs                                6.6.3 (cli-only)
typescript                          4.1.6 (cli-only)
webpack                             4.46.0 (cli-only)

After deleting the @angular folders in C:\Users\userid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules and re-installing I still got the Angular: , so I installed the core again and I still get the above.. :(

Could you install @angular/core at the root level also? might fix it!
npm install -g @angular/core@11.2.19

else go the below path and delete all @angular/* related dependencies and install again
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm


This is what it showed after installing @angular/core@11.2.14 (there isn't a core for 11.2.19). It shows that it's cli only and more packages came w/ an error

I edited the main post to show what the outcome was
